# How to pass on the output of a function to a sigmoid's function?

Tags: python, sigmoid

I am trying to write a sigmoid function that uses a euler's number rounded up to the 5th decimal places (2.71828)

Here's what I got:

```
from math import e

def e_with_precision(n):
return '%.*f' % (n, e)
print (e_with_precision(5))

def sigmoid(x):
return 1 / (1 + e_with_precision(5)**x)

print(sigmoid(0.5)
```

When I run the code I got:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'float'

The first function returns the rounded up e, when I tested the two functions separately (with some changes) they both worked. But I have no idea how to properly tie them together.

New to coding, please help!

Comment: `e_with_precision` returns a `str`, which you are using `**` on with a `float`. What were the changes you made that made them work?

Comment: When I use return 1 / (1 + e**x), the sigmoid function worked on its own. Not when I replace the value 'e' with the rounded up 'e_with_precision'.

Answer (score 1):

As C.Nivis said correctly, `e_with_precision`returns a string (word/sentence), but python can not calculate with this data type. It needs to be a float (floating point number). You can use

```
def e_with_precision(n):
    return round(e, n) # rounds e to n digits
```

and it should work.

Comment: from math import e
    def e_with_precision(n):
        return round(n, e)
    def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + round(5)**x)
    print(sigmoid(0.5))